# PostgreSQL: Performance: ORDER BY an indexed column is slowing down the query performance

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, aggregate, order-by

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.updated_at, COUNT(*) OVER ()
FROM screens s
INNER JOIN theatres t ON s.theatre_id = t.id 
LEFT JOIN company_screen_mappings AS csm ON csm.screen_id = s.id AND csm.is_deleted = FALSE AND csm.company_id = 'f5003aa3-3621-498a-ab0f-526706fda88f'
WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY s.name asc  LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Here is the query plan:
https://explain.depesz.com/s/UC9B

Here are the indexes in the associated tables

```
CREATE INDEX idx_screens_name ON public.screens USING btree (name);
CREATE INDEX idx_screens_number ON public.screens USING btree (((data ->> 'number'::text)));
CREATE INDEX idx_screens_tags ON public.screens USING gin (tags);
CREATE INDEX idx_screens_theatre_id ON public.screens USING btree (theatre_id);

CREATE INDEX idx_theatre_companies ON public.theatres USING gin (company_ids);
CREATE INDEX idx_theatres_chain_name ON public.theatres USING btree ((((data -> 'chain'::text) ->> 'name'::text)));
CREATE INDEX idx_theatres_city_name ON public.theatres USING btree (((((data -> 'address'::text) -> 'city'::text) ->> 'name'::text)));
CREATE INDEX idx_theatres_country_name ON public.theatres USING btree (((((data -> 'address'::text) -> 'country'::text) ->> 'name'::text)));
CREATE INDEX idx_theatres_name ON public.theatres USING btree (name);
CREATE INDEX idx_theatres_province_name ON public.theatres USING btree (((((data -> 'address'::text) -> 'province'::text) ->> 'name'::text)));
CREATE INDEX idx_theatres_qwc_is_active ON public.theatres USING btree (qwc_is_active);
CREATE INDEX idx_theatres_tags ON public.theatres USING gin (tags);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX company_screen_mappings_key ON public.company_screen_mappings USING btree (company_id, screen_id) WHERE (is_deleted = false);
```

The moment I remove `ORDER BY s.name` the query is considerably fast.
However, `s.name` is indexed, why is this happening?
Is there a way I could optimize the query?
Please suggest.

I need the result ordered by name.
I could notice that removing `COUNT(*) OVER()` greatly improves the query execution time. But I need the `COUNT` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal that retrieving a sorted result is more effort.

If you want the total count, all rows have to be scanned, even if you only return the first 50.

You could try `order by name || ''` to see if a sort would be faster.

My recommendation is **not** to retrieve the total count together with the query.

The optimizer's estimates are good in this case, so you should use an approximate result count by running

```
EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON) SELECT ...
```

and retrieving the `Plan Rows`.

Comment: WOW! that absolutely works.
However, I don't quiet understand what "You could try order by name || '' '' to see if an explicit sort would be faster." means.
I am already trying to "explicitly sort by name in ascending order". How does ORing by '' make it more explicit?

Much Thanks :)

Comment: I was unclear. I mean an execution plan that contains a `Sort` node rather than sorting by retrieving rows in index order.